# Excel: Finding max value based on two criteria, if max value has two identical results

Tags: excel, max

If we have a table of sports teams, that have all played against each other and two teams are on top equal with x points, the winner would be crowned with the highest average goal differential.

But how would you do that with a formula in Excel?

[image]

This is the formula I am using to find the team with the highest points total:

=INDEX($C$8:$C$11,MATCH(MAX($K$8:$K$11),$K$8:$K$11,0))

This formula would give me the result of Ecuador being highest (first result of max value).

But in reality Qatar should be on top based on same points total AND average goal difference being higher.

Any solutions?

Comment: So have a column with the sum or product of points & goal diff and use match() with max() to find the highest value then index() to get the name.

Comment: @SolarMike i was thinking at first about the same idea, but a situation like this for columns `GD` and `P`: `{2,3;3,2}` will produce an equal result for both rows doing sum or prod. In this case the first place will be row `1` and the second place row `2` based on the `P` criteria, there is no need to take into consideration the second criteria (`GD`) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to sort in descending order first by column **P**, then by column **GD**. If that is not the case, you can adjust it accordingly. In cell `A8` you can put the following formula:

```
=TAKE(SORT(A3:I6, {9,8}, -1),2,1)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample output file]

You can also select the columns of your interest first via `CHOOSECOLS` then `SORT`:

```
=TAKE(SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A3:I6,1,8,9), {3,2}, -1),2,1)
```

If you want to include the row title, then:

```
=HSTACK({"First Place";"Second Place"},TAKE(SORT(A3:I6, {9,8}, -1),2,1))
```

**Note**: `MATCH/XMATCH` is not appropriate in this context, because what you really need is to sort the result, not finding values that match certain conditions. You can do it, but at the end you will end up implementing a sort manually and Excel has a built-in function for that. The resulting formula will unnecessary more verbose.

With `SORT` function you can use more than one criteria indicating in an array the columns to consider as first and second criteria, etc.. For your example it would be: `{9,8}` indicating as first sorting criteria column `9` and then column `8`, so if column **P** have the same value, then it sorts by **GD**. The third input argument is to specify ascending (`1`, default)/descending order(`-1`). If you want to have a different sorting criteria for each column, then instead of `-1`, you can use it `{-1,1}` which means sort in descending order the column `9` and in ascending order the column `8`. For your case you can use also: `{-1,-1}`, but using `-1` produce the same result.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, David. But I only want the team name, without having to sort the table itself. Therefore I have the formula mentioned in the problem above. Do you have any solution for this? Should also mention that I have this document on Google Drive, as it is a shared document, where this SORT solution does not seem to work (or at least I have not yet figured it out).

Comment: You can adapt my solution to return just the team names based on the sorting criteria you defined: `=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(A3:I6, {9,8}, -1),1)` or just: `=INDEX(SORT(A3:I6, {9,8}, -1),,1)`. I don't follow your formula, in the screenshot I cannot see the column letters nor the row numbers. So it is difficult to understand your formula. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again, David. I apologize for the unclarity in previously given image.  I've updated the question accordingly, with a more clear image.

Comment: I am going to update the answer, but basically it is the same solution. First place: `=INDEX(SORT(A3:I6, {9,8}, -1),1,1)` and Second place: `=INDEX(SORT(A3:I6, {9,8}, -1),2,1)`your formula doesn't consider the scenario the first criteria are equal, then you need to search by the second criteria.

Comment: All your solutions much appreciated, David. They all work in Excel, but in Google Sheets (Google Drive) they do not however.